# This program is supposed to trigger the 'if' statements at the bottom but it wont as is. How can I get this to work?

Tags: c++

I've tried a bunch of garbage to try and get the variables right but I keep screwing it up and I can't figure out where to place the variables correctly. I'm also having a really hard time placing my if and else if statements.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int iseed = time(NULL);
  srand(iseed);
  int min = 1;
  int max = 6;
  int sum1 = 0;
  int sum2 = 0;
  int A = 0;
  int B = 0;

  int C = min + rand() % (max - min +1);
  int D = min + rand() % (max - min +1);


  char repeat2;
  char repeat1;

  cout << "Beat the computer!\n";

  do {
        int A = min + rand() % (max - min +1);
        int B = min + rand() % (max - min +1);
        int sum1 = A + B;

        cout << "you rolled a " << A << " and a " << B << endl;
        cout << "Total roll = " << sum1 << endl;
        cout << "Would you like to keep this roll? Y or N: ";
        cin >> repeat1;

     } while (repeat1 == 'N');

        cout << "The computer rolled a " << C << " and a " << D << endl;
        cout << "Total roll = " << sum2 << endl;


        if (sum2 > sum1) {cout << "You lose! D= YOU ROLLED " << sum1 << "HE ROLLED " << sum2 << ".";}
        else if (sum1 < sum2) {cout << "You win! =D ";}
        else if (sum1 = sum2) {cout << "It's a tie /= ";}
        cout << "Would you like to play again?: ";
        cin >> repeat2;

}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: So if you have a hard time placing your if- statements, you should look more into how the flow of your program is supposed to work, e.g. with flow charts. Also, variables exist in different scopes. Try to look that up for C++ (keywords: Scope, variables) And please ask a specific question to which a answer can be provided without assuming too much.

Comment: `else if (sum1 = sum2)` should be `else if (sum1 == sum2)`. Otherwise you're assigning sum2 to sum1 and the if triggers when sum2 is nonzero. You can also remove the `if()` part because equality is the only thing left if sum1 is neither larger nor smaller than sum2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Problem 1

`int sum1 = A + B;` in the `do`/`while` loop declares a new `sum1` that hides `int sum1 = 0;` as a result, nothing ever changes the outer `sum1` from 0.

## Solution 1

change

```
int sum1 = A + B;
```

to

```
sum1 = A + B;
```

## Problem 2

Nothing sums `C` and `D` to provide a non-zero `sum2`.

## Solution 2

Add in

```
sum2 = C + D;
```

## Problem 3

```
if (sum2 > sum1)
else if (sum1 < sum2)
```

both test the same condition, that the player's rolls are less than the computer's rolls.

## Solution 3

Change

```
else if (sum1 < sum2)
```

to

```
else if (sum2 < sum1)
```

To avoid problems like this in the future, give variable good descriptive names. It's a lot easier to see that `sum_player` was accidentally swapped with `sum_computer` than it is to spot that `sum1` and `sum2` have been exchanged.

## Problem 4

```
else if (sum1 = sum2)
```

is not a comparison. It is an assignment followed by a test that the new value of `sum1` is not 0 (which it will be).

## Solution 4

Use

```
else if (sum1 == sum2)
```

instead.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCHCHCHCHCHCHCHCHCHCH

Comment: sum2 is never calculated, the first and the second conditions are exactly the same, the third overwrites sum1 with 0 that is in sum2 and conditions on that 0... ouuuuch. Edit (and i didn't even notice the sum1 in a local scope, lol)

Comment: @boris Good eyes on the swap of the two variables in the second if.